# how to use thrust::norm for complex number

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to use thrust:: norm for complex vector. But there is an error: no instance of function  'thrust::norm' matches the argument list. Here is my code. fft is a complex vector.

```
thrust::transform(fft.begin(), fft.end(), fft.begin(), thrust::norm<thrust::complex<double>>());
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed it to a another real vector psd. But I still have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To pass an operation to an algorithm like `thrust::transform`, the operation must be expressed in the form of a functor or [a lambda](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/power-cpp11-cuda-7/).  `thrust::norm<thrust::complex<T> >()` is neither of these, it is a "bare" function provided by the thrust [complex.h template header](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__complex__numbers.html).

Therefore, to use it as a thrust algorithm op, we'll need to wrap it somehow.  Here's a simple example of wrapping it in a functor. Since this particular function takes a thrust complex type, but returns a non-complex type, we'll need to make sure our input and output vectors match the needed types:

```
$ cat t1336.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>


struct my_complex_norm {
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(thrust::complex<T> &d){
    return thrust::norm(d);
  }
};

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double> > fft(5);
  thrust::device_vector<double> out(5);

  thrust::transform(fft.begin(), fft.end(), out.begin(), my_complex_norm());
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1336 t1336.cu
$
```

For more information on basic functor usage, I recommend the thrust [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).